# Algebraic structures,counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone tell me example of field that have left  but not  right law of distribution.Is it possible?

Comment: Not a field, no. Distribution in both directions (and for that matter, commutative multiplication which makes the two notions equivalent) is part of the definition.

Comment: If i want to prove distribution i can do it only in direction and i 'm done?

Comment: If your multiplication (whatever operation you have outside the brackets) is commutative, yes, you can.

Comment: Look up "division ring".

Comment: You also got your name wrong, it's linkinpark (/s)

Comment: I know that ,i put it deliberately

Answer (score 1):

Since your question actually asks about an example where one distribution but not the other exists (while I suspect from the comments that you are really after something else, making this an instance of an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info)), here is an example.

Take the set of functions $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ along with the two operations of $\circ$ (composition) and $\cdot$ (pointwise multiplication). Then we have
$$
(f\cdot g)\circ h = (f\circ h)\cdot (g\circ h)
$$
but $h\circ(f\cdot g)$ and $(h\circ f)\cdot (h\circ g)$ are not equal in general. So here we have right distribution but not left distribution of composition over multiplication.

We can take this example and write composition the other way. In other words, take the operation $\bar\circ$ defined by $f\mathbin{\bar\circ} g(x) = g(f(x))$. In that case we do have left distribution but not right distribution.